# Dynamic Paint Baking doesn't work correctly

Tags: texture-painting, dynamic-paint, ocean-simulation

i have a ship that sails on an ocean. Using Dynamic Paint, this ship leaves a trail of paint on the ocean and makes some waves which then dissolves after a few seconds. The ship is set as a brush and the ocean as a canvas. If I run the animation in the viewport, everything works perfectly and the ship draws a track on the ocean when it moves forward. However, when I bake the Dynamic Paint, the paint trail is displayed from the last frame i baked no matter what frame I'm on. But the ship should of course draw this track first. How can I bake it so that the track is drawn correctly with the ship? I would be very happy to receive help!

EDIT: Here is the simplified file: [image]

Here I run it directly over the viewport and stop at frame 20. Everything perfect.
[image]

Here I bake 90 frames and then go back to frame 20. The white trace from frame 90 is still shown.
[image]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128486/discussion-between-vklidu-and-tim).

Comment: Chatting here is not allowed ... I deleted all my comments here. Please do the same. Thank you keep this site organised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name each cache by unique prefix ... without that, baking overwrites previous layer.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much it worked!! Oh yes, that's right, I forgot to activate Dissolve for the test file, but then it worked 

Comment: Thanks for Q ... I learned from it too :)